# JSON data disappears after AJAX call with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm making a quiz and trying to import questions from a JSON file. However when I import the questions and try to make use of them in my js file the data disappears. What am I doing wrong? Would appreciate some help =)!

First I have a question object with properties:

```
function Question(question, choices, correctChoice, userAnswer, type) {

    this.question = question;
    this.choices = choices;
    this.correctChoice = correctChoice;
    this.userAnswer = userAnswer;
    this.type = type;

}
```

I want to import JSON data and turn that data into Question Objects:

```
var allQuestions = [];
var category = "history";
var jsonData = null;

   function callJson(){

        $.ajax({
            url: 'myJsonUrl.json',
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function(data) {
                jsonData = data;
            }
        });  
   }

   $(".btn").click(function(){

       var jsonDataLength = 0; 

       for(var key in jsonData[category])
           jsonDataLength++;

       for(var i=0; i < jsonDataLength; i++) {
           allQuestions[i] = new Question();
           var questionNr = "q" + (i+1).toString();

           for(var properties in jsonData[category][questionNr])
               allQuestions[i][properties] = jsonData[category][questionNr][properties]; 
       }
    alert(allQuestions[0].question); //If i alert this here I get the correct value
    callJson();  
   });
```

Now if I try to use that data anywhere else outside the .btn the question object doesen't have any data:

```
$(".btn-show").on("click", function(){

    alert(allQuestions[0].question);    // This won't work    
});
```

Here's the JSON file:

```
{ 
"history": {    

    "q1": {
        "question": "Which country did Britain fight in the War of Jenkins's Ear?",
        "choices": ["Norway", "India", "Spain", "Turkey"],
        "correctChoice": 2,
        "userAnswer": -1,
        "type": "radio"
    },

    "q2": {
        "question": "What was the largest naval battle of the First World War?",
        "choices": ["Battle of Poltava", "Battle of Jutland", "Battle of Stalingrad", "Battle of Hastings"],
        "correctChoice": 1,
        "userAnswer": -1,
        "type": "radio"
    },

    "q3": {
        "question": "In which year was Abraham Lincoln assassinated?",
        "choices": ["1915", "1755", "1805", "1865"],
        "correctChoice": 3,
        "userAnswer": -1,
        "type": "radio"
    },

    "q4": {
        "question": "Which countries formed the triple entente before the First World War?",
        "choices": ["Italy", "Britain", "France", "Germany", "Austria", "Russia"],
        "correctChoice": [-1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1],
        "userAnswer": [],
        "type": "checkbox"
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Is `callJson()` called anywhere before the `.btn` click handler?

Comment: No not in this example I posted. But I've tried to remove the function itself from the AJAX call so the call should be made at the top of the document and that won't work either.

Comment: Unless I'm reading it wrong, the first time the handler fires `jsonData` will be `null` and only fill in when the last line `callJson()` is called (even then there will be a delay for the round-trip).

Comment: You're right. I've moved the callJson(); up to just below the function callJson. Strangely it won't work either. I'm getting "cannot read property: question of undefined".

Comment: Could you post a sample of the JSON data?

Comment: Yes sir, I've done that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the questions are not being loaded before you're calling for their value. Try this:

```
var allQuestions = [];
var category     = "history";
var jsonData     = null;

function populateQuestions(callback){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'myJsonUrl.json',
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function(data) {
      allQuestions = []; // kill off previous results
      jsonData     = data;

      var jsonDataLength = 0; 

      for (var key in jsonData[category]) {
          jsonDataLength++;
      }

      for (var i=0; i < jsonDataLength; i++) {
        allQuestions[i] = new Question();
        var questionNr = "q" + (i+1).toString();

        for(var properties in jsonData[category][questionNr]) {
          allQuestions[i][properties] = jsonData[category][questionNr][properties]; 
        }
      }

      // if a callback was passed, call it and pass in the questions
      if (typeof callback === 'function') {
          callback(allQuestions);
      }
    }
  }); 
 }

 $('.btn').click(populateQuestions).click();
```

This attaches the `populateQuestions` function to the click of the button and then fires it straight away.

You could do better than the last `click` handler too. You could call:

```
populateQuestions(functionToActuallyDoSomething);
```

With `functionToActuallyDoSomething` being a callback that is passed the fetched questions.

Comment: I'm still getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'question' of undefined" =(.

Comment: Ok, now I'm getting the correct value when I do console.log(allQuestions[0].question);  but it disappears within one second (from the console). Any ideas why?

Comment: LOL, a common problem... the button click is going through as a form submit (if it's an actual `button` element, if it's an anchor tag, it'll go to the `href`), meaning it's reloading the page. Remember to kill off the click event. `$('.x').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); /* your code */ return false; });` The `e.preventDefault()` makes sure the button doesn't do what buttons like to do. The `return false;` does the same, but also ensures that no other handlers fire.

Comment: Thank you very Very much @Kevin!! My first piece of code works just fine when I add e.preventDefault() and return false; to the .btn. Hahaha, you made my day and this has taught me a valuable lesson. Again, thank you!

Comment: @DavidCetinkaya not a problem... I forget to kill off the event about half the time and have that face palm moment. Something to keep in mind, glad you got sorted.

Comment: Great job @KevinNagurski =D!

Answer (score -2):

True, because `allQuestions` is out of scope there. You could try passing it to the click like this:

```
$(".btn-show").on("click", function(allQuestions){
    alert(allQuestions[0].question); // This won't work    
});
```

Comment: Actually, from the code, `allQuestions` is initialised on the global scope.